# re.match function doesn't detect line in file

Tags: python, file, match, python-re

I wanted to detect in which line, the section '' is. I used python to it.
I used re.match(), but it does not detect that obvious line:

```
import re
filereader = open("template.html", "r") 
template = filereader.readlines()
filereader.close()
for d in range(len(template)):
    if re.match(r'.*<body onload="init(0,0);">.*',template[d]):
        wherebody = d
        break
print(wherebody)
```

Where is the error?
Note: HTML file HAS the

Comment: Simple () in a regex is grouping. I guess you need `\(0,0\)` instead of (0,0).

Comment: It is easier to experiment with shorter codes:
`re.match(r'.*<body onload="init\(0,0\);">', r'xxxx<body onload="init(0,0);">yyyy')`. And you don't need the .* at the end. For the question it is not important where does the string come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this example: https://regex101.com/r/6JcYhk/1, your regex does not work in matching text with `<body onload="init(0,0);">`. This is because `(` and `)` are interpreted as the Regex group start and end tokens. You can resolve this by escaping these characters, which matches the literal `(` and `)` instead:

```py
...
    if re.match(r'.*<body onload="init\(0,0\);">.*',template[d]):
...
```

(You can try this out in the aforementioned example, and you'll see that it starts to match)